# Longevity Experiments

Tags: cell-biology, lifespan

I realize this is a bit of a long shot, but sometime this year I was reading a paper about experiments that I believe were performed in Drosophila (may have been planaria) where breeding was delayed until late adulthood through separation of the sexes. After a number of generations there was significant lifespan increase.

Anybody come across this that can point me to it?

Comment: Planaria are hermaphrodites.

Comment: Look into Michael Rose's work at UC Irvine. No sure if this is what you were thinking of.